# How to use MSGraphClient in Outlook office Addin created with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, sharepoint-online

//Updated Code.

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

// images references in the manifest
import "../../assets/icon-16.png";
import "../../assets/icon-32.png";
import "../../assets/icon-80.png";

/* global $, document, Office */
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
import { getGraphData } from "./../helpers/ssoauthhelper";

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    // (document).ready
    $(function () {
      getGraphData();
      $("#saveAttachments").on("click", async function() {
        let checked: number = $(".atchCheckBoxes > input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        for await (const attachment of Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments) {
          Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync(attachment.id, (asyncResult) => {
            saveAttachment(asyncResult.value.content, attachment.name);
            // if (attachment.size > 4 * 1024 * 1024) {
            // }
            // else{
            // }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});

async function saveAttachment(mimeStream: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
  // let graphClient: MSGraphClient = new MSGraphClient();
  // let graphClient: MSGraphClient;
  // var graphClient: Client;

  // here "graphClient" variable is undefined when call this function on "Save Attachment(s)" button click
  // how can save attachments read from email and save in SharePoint Online Document Library
  // if there is any alternative way please suggest me.


  var graphClient: MSGraphClient;
  const odApi = `/me/drive/root:/${fileName}:/content`;
  const saveResult = await graphClient.api(odApi).put(mimeStream);
  console.log(`Save Attachment result for ${fileName}: `, saveResult);
  return saveResult;
}
```

[image]

Hope you guys are doing best, I need some help. In outlook add-in created by TypeScript, I am using graph api to upload attachment in a SharePoint Online document library. I am Importing 'MSGraphClient' like 'import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http' but getting 'MSGraphClient' undefined always. Please see the pictures below.Please help me on this[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code in text format for us to be able to test and find what you are doing wrong. From the looks `graphClient` is null. Please also check [Creating Client Instance](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/HEAD/docs/CreatingClientInstance.md)

Comment: Hi @Danstan, i have updated post with code. can you please check and advice me?